# How to resolve This issue while writing bulk trigger?

Tags: trigger

There was an unexpected error in your org which is preventing this assessment check from completing:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER, We can't save this record because the “Opportunity Management” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details.

my code is:-

```
Trigger ClosedOpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert,after update) {

   List<task> CreateTask=new List<task>();
    for(Opportunity o:Trigger.New)
    {
        if(o.StageName=='closed won')
        {
            Task t= new task();
            t.Subject='follow up task';
            t.WhatId=o.Id;
            CreateTask.add(t);

        }
    }
    if(CreateTask.size()>0)
    {
        insert CreateTask;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't find any issue in your trigger, go to Setup > Process Builder or Flow, A process or flow named "Opportunity Management" should be there in the org, there you need to check for the issue.

One most common case is, for example, you are getting a field from lookup record, but the lookup field itself is not having any value. Please check and update your question accordingly if needed.

Comment: ya, after deactivating "Opportunity Management" in process builder . i get a new error "Executing against the trigger does not work as expected.".What does it mean?

Comment: Are you trying to complete any trailhead challenge?

Comment: Yeah, Apex Bulk trigger link=https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk

Comment: You need to correct the task subject as mentioned in the challenge.. `t.Subject = 'Follow Up Test Task'`

Comment: resolved ,Thank you.!